# How to deploy whole Wordpress app in Nuxt app?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Is there any possibiliy to deploy full wordpress app in Nuxt app? I mean I want to have adress `foo.com` of my app and on `foo.com/bar` will be wordpress app. Is there any way to do this? Nuxt router will be able to deal with this?

Wordpress API and iframe aren't answers, which I look for. As I said i want to deploy whole wordpress on specific adress of my Nuxt app.

Comment: It is possible but not directly using NodeJS web server, you need to configure your app in a way that nuxt server is serving on a different port and then use Nginx as reverse proxy to achieve what you need

Comment: Got any documentation or tutorial how to do this?

Comment: Why not using Wordpress as a headless CMS in this case ? I don't see the benefit of having both.

Comment: Already got old Wordpress blog and no time to create front-end for new blog

Comment: You should just use a nginx and route /bar to the wordpress site. Make sure to setup the wordpress with the `/bar` path, https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-step-by-step/

Answer (score 1):

A bit of background

- NuxtJS (build as [static](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/commands/#target-static)) is a *client side* app.
- WordPress is a PHP *server side* app
- A wordpress site *usually* get served to users by web servers like `apache` or `nginx`.
- Client side apps served by any web server (including `apache` or `nginx`)

So you can't "deploy wordpress in nuxt", but it is simple to get what you want:

1. Follow this [guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-ii-with-url-change) to move the wordpress to a subdirectory
2. Upload the nuxt app to the root directory

In case you are using SSR or any other requirements that force you to use Nuxt in [server mode](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/commands/#server-deployment), your options are:

- Setup nginx as reverse proxy
- Setup apache as reverse proxy
- Setup a proxy in the node server itself, maybe [this project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/proxy) could help

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a problem with this without the wordpress API, but the question is, do you care about Nuxt.js or maybe just Vue is enough? Remember that in Vue 2 you can use an [inline-template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Inline-Templates), thanks to which you can render elements on the server side. For this you will add the necessary elements from the Vue ecosystem, such as a router and setup you will have similar to Nuxt.js.
Example code:

```html
<div is="navbar-dropdown" inline-template>
    <div v-cloak :class="isOpenDropdown ? 'visible opacity-1 mt-0' : 'invisible opacity-0 mt-10'">
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```